# Как добавить кнопку в textarea

Tags: html, css

У меня есть простая формочка для ввода текста.Хочу добавить кнопку для удаления текста в правом углу формы, что-то наподобии этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока получилось только так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.btn-default {
  background: #DC50FF;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.form-control {
  width: 30%;
}

.clear {
  position: relative;
  right: 28px;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
 Browse <input #file type="file" hidden accept=".pptx">
 </label><br><br>
<p>Description of presentation :</p>

<form>
  <div>
    <textarea name="fileDescription" [(ngModel)]="desc" class="form-control" rows="2 "></textarea>
    <button class="clear" (click)="clear()">&#215;</button>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
<button (click)="upload(file.files)" class="btn btn-primary"> Upload</button>
<br />
```

Answer (score 2):

Оберните пару дивом, спозиционируйте кнопку абсолютно:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <textarea name="fileDescription" [(ngModel)]="desc" class="form-control" rows="2 "></textarea>
    <button>X</button>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: как ее правильней спозиционировать , если в моем .css  `textarea {
  
  width: 30%;
} `

Comment: и еще,ее закрепить как то можно? чтобы при растягивании формы растягивалась и эта  кнопка.

Comment: исправила, делайте ширину обертывающему контейнеру, а самой textarea задавайте его 100% ширину

Answer (score 2):

Если позволяют соседние элементы справа от *textarea*, то без создания дополнительных обёрток и с минимумом кода:

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  right: 28px;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="fileDescription" [(ngModel)]="desc" class="form-control" rows="2 ">Измените размер. Нажмите кнопку.</textarea>
<button onclick="this.previousElementSibling.value = '';">&#215;</button>
```

#### UPD

При `position: relative`, отступ неизбежен. Но, метода проще, чем ограничить изменение размера, я не вижу:

```css
.btn-default {
  background: #DC50FF;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.form-control {
  min-height: 2em;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 18px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 35px);
}

.clear {
  position: relative;
  right: 28px;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
 Browse <input #file type="file" hidden accept=".pptx">
</label><br><br>
<p>Description of presentation :</p>

<form>
  <div>
    <textarea name="fileDescription" [(ngModel)]="desc" class="form-control" rows="2 "></textarea>
    <button class="clear" (click)="clear()">&#215;</button>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
<button (click)="upload(file.files)" class="btn btn-primary"> Upload</button>
<br />
```

Эксперименты с `position: absolute` (из прочих ответов) показали, что без дополнительной разметки, кнопка также скачет, при появлении полосы прокрутки у `body`.

Comment: увы,после вашего кода,кнопка остается под textarea

Comment: @richardgir потому и упомянуто про соседние элементы. Мы же не видим всей вашей разметки и стилей.

Comment: добавил полную разметку

Comment: @richardgir дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. У меня проблема заключается в том,чтобы как бы я не изменял css, кнопка не оказывается внутри textarea

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form>
<div>
<textarea></textarea>
<button style="position: absolute; margin-left: -35px;">X</button>
</div>
<br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
textarea {
  display:flex;
}

.clear {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.cont {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="cont">
    <button class="clear" (click)="clear()">&#215;</button>
<textarea  name="fileDescription" [(ngModel)]="desc" class="form-control" rows="2 "></textarea>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

Вот нашел приближенное,к тому что хотел получить.

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы ваша разметка поддавалась редактированию нужно придерживаться некоторых правил.

Во первых, Вы не корректно используете тег `<br>`.
Ознакомьтесь с описанием [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/br)  и посмотрите правильное и неправильно использование [тут](https://github.com/hail2u/html-best-practices#dont-use-br-element-only-for-presentational-purpose.)

Во вторых, Вы используете атрибут `rows="2"` для задания высоты textarea, но его ширину устанавливаете в CSS при помощи:

```
.form-control {
  width: 30%;
}
```

Выберете один стиль оформления для тестового поля что бы не путаться и Ваш код оставался поддерживаемым.

В третьих, Вы не корректно используете свойство `position`. [В этом примере](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position.) хорошо описана разница между relative и absolute.

В четвёртых, [ознакомьтесь с свойством](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing) `box-sizing`, оно поможет исправить ситуацию с тем что у кнопки будет отступ от края тестового поля.

Рабочий пример с учётом рекомендаций:

```css
.btn-default {
  background: #DC50FF;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.textarea-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.textarea-wrapper textarea.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.textarea-wrapper .textarea-clear {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        Browse <input #file type="file" hidden accept=".pptx">
    </label>
<p>Description of presentation :</p>

<form>
  <div class="textarea-wrapper">
    <textarea name="fileDescription" [(ngModel)]="desc" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <button class="textarea-clear" (click)="clear()">&#215;</button>
  </div>
</form>
<button (click)="upload(file.files)" class="btn btn-primary"> Upload</button>
```

Comment: спасибо за ценный комментарий. Но тут остается проблема с адаптивностью кнопки.То есть она остается на месте при растягивании формы.

Comment: `.textarea-wrapper {
width:100%
}` И кнопка будет всегда в правом углу

Comment: @richardgir Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score -1):

```
<button style="position: absolute;margin: 1px -30px;">X</button>
```